# how to implement IPinFlowControl interface in Directshow

Tags: visual-c++, directshow

i want to implement `IPinFlowControl` interface, and it has one method Block.

i had tried with below code,

```
Mux::NonDelegatingQueryInterface(REFIID iid, void** ppv)
{
   if(iid==IID_IPinFlowControl)
    {
    return GetInterface((IPinFlowControl*) this, ppv);
    }

    return CBaseFilter::NonDelegatingQueryInterface(iid, ppv);
}


STDMETHODIMP Mux::Block(DWORD dwBlockFlags,HANDLE hEvent)
{
    return S_OK;
}
```

and register above filter.

now in code i create instance of above filter, connect its output pins and then try

```
IPin *pMuxOut2 = NULL;
hr = FindUnconnectedPin(mux,PINDIR_OUTPUT,&pMuxOut2);

IPinFlowControl *pinFlowControl=NULL;

hr=pMuxOut2->QueryInterface(IID_IPinFlowControl,(void**)&pinFlowControl);
```

But i got E_NonInterface in pinFlowControl,

also please help me to implement block method properly to Block and Unblock output.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to implement `IPinFlowControl` on your filter, you should take a look at [`CDynamicOutputPin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374458%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class provided with BaseClasses.

[Synth Filter Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407178%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Windows SDK provides you with an example of deriving from this class.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you implement the interface on a filter, but query for that interface on a pin.

If you want to create that interface on a pin, you need to create that, and you have to create a filter which uses that pin implementation.

Comment: Thanks @Wimmel , i'll look out that and ll back to you :)